# Java: Use string array as variable name holder and then use variables elsewhere via array index

Tags: arrays, string, variables, indexing

I'm trying to use a string array as a holder of different variable names and then use an incremental array index to call on those variables.  So I create a string array and call it `frac[]` and then within each index I add a string of frac1, frac2, frac3, etc. with each string having its own index.  The variables frac1,2,3,etc. were already created individually and now I want to call on those variables to use them in a different area of my code but I want to use the array so that I can cycle through different indexes (variables) with a counter.  **How can I tell Java to use the specific index of the string array as a variable name?**

Code for array to input the 5 pre-existing variable names:

```
for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++){
    frac[w] = "frac" + (w + 1);
}
```

Where I want to use array index (frac[z]):

```
for (int z = 1; z < 2; z++){
    System.out.println("Please enter your numerator for fraction # " + z + ": ");
    n = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter your denominator for fraction # " + z + ": ");
    d = keyboard.nextInt();
    frac[z] = new Fraction (n,d);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `for` line: `for (int z = 1; z < 2; z++)` will be done only for once as z from 1 to little than 2 which means it will work only when z=1

Comment: Oops I didn't mean to post it that way.  I shrunk the numbers so that I could test it without having to put in so many options.  Normally it would read z = 0; z < 5; z++.  Good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what your goal is, have you considered using a java.util.Map ? There are some implementation (TreeMap, HashMap ....)

It's a simple data structure where you define a key-value entry:

```
TreeMap<String,Fraction> frMap = new TreeMap<String,Fraction>();
frMap.put("fraz1",new Fraction(1,2));
Fraction f = frMap.get("fraz1");
```

Comment: I've never used this before so I'm a little confused.  What is the last line doing?  It looks like Fraction F is creating a new variable which if that's the case then it kind of puts me back to square one.  The string "frac1" in string array index [0] needs to be fraction # 1 out of 5 total fractions that my program needs to create.  I then need to modify each individual fraction with a class that I created for reducing, getting decimal, etc.  I could write this manually for all five fractions but a key goal in this class is to write shorter code so that's why I'm trying to use an array.

Comment: these 3 lines of code are just an example of how to "write" and how to "read" data from a Map. I expand my answer to loop for 5 different Faction.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting this to work now.  I'll keep playing with it for a while and I'll post if I'm successful.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it's not really clear what your goal is,
but you can use java reflection to get property value from its name:

example use of reflection:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public int a;

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
    s.a = 5;
    try {
      int b = (Integer) SomeClass.class.getField("a").get(s);
      System.out.println(b);
    } catch  (Exception e)  {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

note that most times (some would say) the use of reflection notes bad design.